# SIMPLE Django button to execute view function

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, variables, button

After a few days of tutorials I am calling it quits, any help would be appreciated. Can't get this to work, I'm sure it's easy, but this stuff is extremely convoluted. Just trying to delete a session variable with a button. I tried Ajax examples as well. Please don't forward me to another post unless you are sure it will actually work, because many do not.

```
URL: urls.py
...
url(r'^$', clear_session, name='clear_session'),
...
```

and

```
View: views.py

def clear_session(request):

    print('hello')

    if not request.POST:

        print('hello')
        del request.session['jobs_append']

        print('session list', request.session['jobs_append'])
```

and

```
Template: index.html

...
<input id="clear_sesh" name="update_log" type="button" value="Update Log"/>
...

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#clear_sesh").click(function(){
    $.post(
     url : "/clear_session/",
     dataType:"html",
     success: function(data, status, xhr){
        //do something with your data
    }
    );
    return false;
});
});
</script>
...

    <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'vendor/scrollreveal/scrollreveal.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>

<!-- Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="{% static 'js/creative.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: your ajax url is not correct. put a `/` instead

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any issue with the code of the view, but your url code and your jQuery call isn't right, because you url for that view is empty, meaning that view is called in your first page (ex. `127.0.0.1:8000`), but you are calling the url "/clear_session/" (ex. `127.0.0.1:8000/clear_session/`) with AJAX, in summary you are never calling your view and by extend your code never is executed.

**UPDATE**

This is a working example that should help you to make your views. Also I found an issue with your AJAX call, you should be using a request type other than `post` because you're explicitly excluding post requests within your view. Now the example:

urls.py

```
url(r'^clear-session-url/$', clear_session, name='clear_session_name'),
url(r'^update-session-url/$', update_session, name='update_session_name')
```

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def clear_session(request):
    if not request.POST:
        del request.session['jobs_append']
    return JsonResponse({'jobs_append': request.session.get('jobs_append', None)})


def update_session(request):
    if not request.POST:
        request.session['jobs_append'] = True
    return JsonResponse({'jobs_append': request.session.get('jobs_append', None)})
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('/update-session-url/', function(data) {console.log(data)});
    $.get('/clear-session-url/', function(data) {console.log(data)});
</script>
```

I added a second view to allow easy testing and to empathize how you should be using your urls. Also used different strings for all parameters to reduce the confusion you have with the url function. **Note:** you'll see the results of this calls in your browser's javascript console.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but I want to stay on the same page, there is no new URL. Is not the `name='clear_session'` the name of the url?

Comment: The page reloading and the view url aren't related. Your page isn't going to be reloaded if you call the view that deletes the session key with AJAX and use type="button" in your HTML button. So to fix your issue you only have to change your url to `url(r'^clear_session/$', clear_session, name='clear_session')`

Comment: Regarding to your other question the name of the url is just an identifier that Django uses to reverse the name to an url.

Comment: That does not fix it, but I will keep trying. The first and third item in the URL pattern I am still confused about. Other forms/views in my program work with `r'^$'` as my URL... I am not getting an error onClick, I just get no response from server and my session variable remains as is.

Comment: Does the ajax call your views?

Comment: Try calling the url using a REST client like REST Easy for firefox instead of calling it from jQuery because you may be calling `127.0.0.1:8000//clear_session/` instead of `127.0.0.1:8000/clear_session/` also use `django.urls.reverse` function to make sure which url calls your view. Your other forms maybe are being included from other url confs and appear to share the same url but they aren't, I'm telling you to check all this because as far as I know you cannot have two or more views with the same url, one will replace the others, leaving problems as the ones you are experiencing.

Comment: The first param in the url function is the urlpattern associated with view, in less words the pattern is more or less the relative url (the difference is that a pattern it allows you to match dynamic urls like those containing an integer, but without specifying which one) from which you can access your view, the third param is just a name that you use to internally identify your url in django (this name isn't related to the url that the browser uses to access your view) and it's used by functions like `django.urls.reverse` to generate the relative url from the pattern.

Comment: I am trying all this, but honestly, this shouldn't be this difficult. Basically, I have to open another url (webpage) to delete a variable?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to make a new template page and redirect there. `<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='clear_session.html'" value="click">` This loads a blank page in the same tab and to have it open in a new browser window i.e. _blank it needs some tweeking, but I'm done with the ajax/jquery that doesn't work. I really don't want a new page to open but I'll have to redirect the new page back to the original page if I can do that.

Comment: I updated my answer to add an example of how you should be doing your views and urls.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work without any script:

```
template: index.html

<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='clear_session.html'" value="Clear Session">
```

and

```
view: views.py

def clear_sesh(request):

print('SESSION CLEARED')

request.session.pop("jobs_append", None)

return redirect('index')
```

and

```
URL: urls.py

url('clear_session', clear_sesh, name='clear_sesh')
```

and it now redirects to where I want. Do you see any issue with my solution? I think understanding that url patterns can't overlap was useful to me, so the redirect was seemingly golden.

Also, I am still new to SO, should I test your solution and mark your answer as successful/upvote?